# NDK x86_64 giving reloc error when trying to link in x64 assembly language

Tags: assembly, android-ndk, x86-64

I'm trying to build my native code to target the new 64-bit ABIs in Android 5.0. My 32-bit code (which includes C and assembly language) builds and links correctly. When I try to add assembly language to my x86_64 build, I get the following error:

```
E:/android/FIV_Free//obj/local/x86_64/objs/pil_lib/test.o: requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried adding "-fPIC" to the compile flags, but it had no effect.

Here is the build script:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -D_GCC_ANDROID=1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
          pqv_jni.c \
          pil_io.c \
          pil.c \
          test.S \
endif
```

And here is a simple example of code that compiles, but won't link (in test.S):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
 .global myfunction

 .data
myprivatedata: .byte 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

 .text
myfunction:
  xor rax,rax
  lea rcx,myprivatedata
  mov al,[rcx]
  ret
 .end
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-fPIC` of course has no effect on hand written assembly code, it's a flag for the C compiler instructing it to generate position independent code.  In this scenario, you are the compiler, so you have to write PIC yourself. Luckily, x86-64 helps you with it by providing a new RIP-relative addressing mode. As such, you just need to replace `lea rcx,myprivatedata` with `lea rcx,[rip+myprivatedata]`.

Comment: Right you are :). Thanks; I've been doing x64 asm code on Windows for years, but never saw info about doing it as PIC.